# How to specify the currency for GoogleFinance historical data

Tags: google-finance

I'm having a problem using Google Finance historical data. I need to know the price a particular stock had on a particular date (Usually within the last month).

The problem is, when I use a URL such as https://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=abx I get different results depending on where I issue the query from.

At home I'm in Argentina and my production server is in the US... when I run the query locally I get the prices in AR$, but when run from the server I get USD (Which is what I actually need).

I tried using a X-Forwared-For header but didn't make a difference...

Ideally I'd like to send an extra parameter (something like cur=USD) to explicitly ask for USD... is there such a thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use, currency conversion along with the price of the stock.

For Example:

```
Price of ABB Ltd in SEK = GOOGLEFINANCE("ABB","price") * GOOGLEFINANCE(("CURRENCY:USDSEK"))
```

Then I format the cells, rows, columns with prices to local currency(i.e. SEK) as mentioned in the link: [Format Numbers in excel](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

You could add other parameters such as date as mentioned in below link:
[Get exchange rate on a specific date from GoogleFinance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310642/get-exchange-rate-on-a-specific-date-from-googlefinance)