# Get exchange rate on a specific date from GoogleFinance

Tags: google-sheets, currency, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I'm having trouble stopping the googlefinance function on a specific date to use "that" specific exchange rate to convert currency from GBP to EUR.

Here is my formulae: `=Finance!B4*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR","price",date(2017,15,11))`

Here is the error: `When evaluating GOOGLEFINANCE, the query for the symbol: 'CURRENCY:GBPEUR' returned no data.`

I've looked at other solutions on SO but none to avail. I've actually added **"date"** and **"price"** to my formulae from other solutions. Like so:- [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607627/on-google-spreadsheet-how-can-you-query-googlefinance-for-a-past-exchange-rate)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First of all, `date(2017,15,11)` means the 11th day of 15th month of the year, so you'll need to swap the month and day.

Secondly, historical data queries, such as

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR", "price", date(2017,11,15))
```

return a table with columns and headers.

```
Date                Close
11/15/2017 23:58:00 1.1163
```

From the way you use this formula, I see you just want the exchange rate. Wrap the function in `index(..., 2, 2)` to get the second cell in second row.

```
=index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR", "price", date(2017,11,15)), 2, 2)
```

Comment: @user6655984 What if instead of the date I need to use a refernce to call with the date? Say =index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR", "price", date(A5)), 2, 2)???

Comment: @AlexShevyakov it would be: `=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR", "price", A5), 2, 2)`

Comment: perfect, just what I needed (head scratching with the specific result in the same cell as the formula.

Answer (score 10):

Just to make sure it's known, the `,` operator isn't used in today's Google Sheets, so the correct expression to avoid a parser error would be (in your case):

```
=index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR"; "price"; date(2017;11;15)); 2; 2)
```

Comment: Google sheet help pages use the `,` separator though... https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281

Comment: This is a time saver,.. sometimes it uses the `,` don't know why, but in one of my sheets it is. Maybe depend on language settings of the sheet.

Comment: @Cyber, I did a simple test creating an en-US interfaced new spreadsheet, with Locale: United States settings, and the expression on this answer worked. I also put this expression on a 2015 last edited spreadsheet with Brazilian settings (to check if it's due to old version) and it worked too. So I guess I can't say why comma is accepted on your spreadsheet sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

In Google Sheets, I have done like this, using semicolons:

```
=index(googlefinance("currency:USDNOK";"price";G11);2;2)
```

G11 is my cell containing the date. It seems to do the work for me. I tested it with todays date in G11 and got the same result as for this simplified version for today's currency rate:

```
=googlefinance("currency:USDNOK")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my version of this formula.

Where `B3` should be valid date.

```
=index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDCNY", "price", B3), 2, 2)
```

PS.
I'm not sure why, but when I specify the 15-Dec-2018 the formula shows me an error. 
All other dates are work correct.

Answer (score 1):

your issue is (was) that you trying to force data for non-existing 15th month. syntax for `DATE` is:

```
=DATE(YEAR(), MONTH(), DAY())
```

so the full formula should be:

```
=Finance!B4*INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR", "price", DATE(2017, 11, 15)), 2, 2)
```

alternatives are:

```
=Finance!B4*INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR", "price", "15/11/2014"), 2, 2)
```

---

```
=Finance!B4*INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR", "price", DATEVALUE("15/11/2014")), 2, 2)
```

---

```
=Finance!B4*INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR", "price", A1), 2, 2)
```

where A1 contains valid date

Answer (score 0):

15-Dec-2018 is a Sunday - hence the error. You can add a -2 or +2 because the error will also pop up on Saturdays. I prefer the -2

Comment: I never encountered this issue for weekend days.