# Locking GOOGLEFINANCE exchange rate at the moment when data is input

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, converters, currency

First post on stackoverflow, so please bear with me.

I use a google spreadsheet to track my expenses. As I have expenses in both EUR and Swiss Francs, I would like to program it, so that when I input some expenses in CHF, it converts to EUR using the exchange rate at that current moment and not further updating it (possibily using GOOGLEFINANCE function).
Would this be possible to achieve?

I tried different formulations of GOOGLEFINANCE: if the cell has the function =GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:CHFEUR") it will constantly update the cell, so the value of my expense will constantly change. The other option would be to fetch the exchange rate for a given day, but that is also not what I want.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Excel or Googlesheet? Which as they are different.

Comment: I'm using Googlesheet

Comment: Been edited for you, choose the correct tags.

Comment: Related questions: [On Google Spreadsheet how can you query 'GoogleFinance' for a past exchange rate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20607627/1330560) and [Get exchange rate on a specific date from GoogleFinance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47310642/1330560).